# VBA Save As resulting undefined file type

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple VBA that runs the same report several times while cycling through different names, saving each report as a seperate workbook.

Everything works fine, but 1 of the reports is always saved as an 'undefined' file type, and I have to manual change it to excel afterwards. All others save fine, so I can't figure out the issue. I've tried playing with the SaveAs FileFormat, but none of them have solved this.

```
 For Each c In MCH
        Detail.Range("B8:E10000").ClearContents
        Data.Rows("4:4").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
            c.Value
        lr = Data.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        Data.Range("E5:H" & lr).Copy Detail.Range("B8")
        Sheets("Detail").Calculate
        Set name = Detail.Range("B4")
        Sheets("Detail").Copy
        ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & name
        wb.Close False
    Next
```

Comment: Care to post the code?

Comment: sorry wasn't sure it would be useful since it was part of a larger macro, but I've added the portion that involves the saving. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You didn't select the file format.

### Instead of:

```
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & name
```

### Try this:

**Xslx**

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & name, FileFormat:= xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

**Text file (txt)**

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & name, FileFormat:= xlUnicodeText, CreateBackup:=False
```

For other **FileFormat**s see this enumeration:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241279(v=office.12).aspx

### In case of issues

In case you are experiencing issues with the above do the following:

1. Go to the `Developer` Tab
2. Click on <kbd>Record Macro</kbd>
3. Save the file manually in the desired format
4. Click on <kbd>Stop Recording</kbd>
5. Open your VBA Project and get the generated code

Comment: Just curious to know that if I set the value of name(variable) to "Myfile.txt", could the script save a .txt file for me?

Comment: For text files replace `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` with `xlUnicodeText`

Comment: I had tried that, but it still doesn't work for one particular file. Would something around the name of the file maybe cause the issue?

Comment: Yes there may be several issues. Please see updated post section `In case of issues`. Please follow this scenario to see where the issue lies

Comment: I think I've found the issues. The name that is causing the issue is 3.1 Philip Lim, so when I save the file with that name I think the decimal is causing the undefined file type. Is there a way to work around the decimal in the name without creating a particular rule?

Comment: The `.` should not be an issue. Post the whole file name.